# unable to run bitbake

Tags: beagleboneblack, bitbake

can't able to run bitbake command if do so i get following errors

```
joe@joe-O-E-M:~/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/build$ bitbake core-image-minimal
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 162, in wrapped
    return func(fn, *args)
  File "/home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 172, in parse_config_file
    return bb.parse.handle(fn, data, include)
  File "/home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py", line 99, in handle
    return h['handle'](fn, data, include)
  File "/home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/parse_py/ConfHandler.py", line 147, in handle
    feeder(lineno, s, fn, statements)
  File "/home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/parse_py/ConfHandler.py", line 184, in feeder
    raise ParseError("unparsed line: '%s'" % s, fn, lineno);
ParseError: ParseError at /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/build/conf/bblayers.conf:12: unparsed line: 'BBLAYERS ?= " /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/meta /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/meta-yocto /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/meta-yocto-bsp '

ERROR: Unable to parse /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/build/conf/bblayers.conf: ParseError at /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/build/conf/bblayers.conf:12: unparsed line: 'BBLAYERS ?= " /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/meta /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/meta-yocto /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/meta-yocto-bsp '
```

please help me to resolve it i am using ubentu 16.04

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your 2nd line from the end:

```
ParseError: ParseError at /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/build/conf/bblayers.conf:12: unparsed line: 'BBLAYERS ?= " /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/meta /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/meta-yocto /home/joe/BeagleBone/poky-dora-10.0.1/meta-yocto-bsp '
```

indicates that you lacks an ending `"` in your definition of `BBLAYERS` in `conf/bblayers.conf`